# getting a doc read count of a sub collection in firebase?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to change the structure of part of my Db, it a part that is getting called pretty frequently, thus I am afraid it is going to cost more than one read per call due to my new nesting nature, I want to nest it under a sub doc due so I can protect the whole sub-col by a premium Until value, will this nesting increase the price of since I am querying deep to 1 level plus checking the premium Until value in rules ? would my single call now considered a double call one for the week and one for the weeks ??

// Call

```js
    let collectionRef = collection(db, 'Weeks', id, 'week');
    // get a specific doc in that sub-collection.
```

// Db Model

[image: Top Lvl]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nesting of a document doesn't affect how much it costs to read it.  One document read is always going to cost the same, no matter what the collection it comes from.

Comment: so no manner how deep drilled a doc is the read cost is simply the same. it could be a end level 100 doc you wont charge for the passing through... you will charge for the end result only. I mentioned in my questing that I want to set read guard to that collection from the entry point could I use the main collection as a gate keeper would this work in practice ?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately and explain what you want  to do, what you tried already, and what isn't working the way you expect.